# Hamburger menu doesnt show in responsive navbar

Tags: css, html, navbar, hamburger-menu

Hello I'm really new in this web programming, just learned a few days ago, and try to make responsive navbar of mine. And I found tutorial on w3school, I followed it, and change some code, but it didnt work as intended. The menu succeed to collapse on desired width, but the hamburger menu doesnt show up. I think I already change and match it with my classes, but I dont know what else is wrong.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```css
.navSection {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-table;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #1c948a;
    z-index: 3;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.navMenu .icon{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navMenu ul li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .navMenu ul li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navMenu.responsive {position: relative;}
  .navMenu.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navMenu.responsive ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.navSectionWrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.homelink {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navlogo {
    width: 30%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #2C3E50;
    position: absolute;
}

.logoimg {
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
}

.logotext {
    font-weight: 600;
    float: right;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.logotext>span {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #33425B;
}

.navMenu {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navMenu>ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.navMenu>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.navMenu>ul>li>a>span {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px
}

.navMenu>ul>li>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 10px
}

.navMenu>ul>li>a:hover {
    color: snow;
}
```

```html
<div class="navSection">
        <div class="navSectionWrapper">
            <div class="navlogo">
                <a href="#" class="homelink">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" class="logoimg">
                        <h2 class="logotext">Let's<span>Go</span></h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navMenu" id="mynavMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">+<span>Download</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("mynavMenu");
            if (x.className === "navMenu") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "navMenu";
            }
        }
</script>
```

ThankYou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML uses `a.icon` but you're targeting in CSS with `li.icon`. Moved the `class="icon"` to the `li` instead of the `a` and modified the CSS for `.icon` a bit. You were hiding `:not(:first-child())` in the responsive view, and you either want to use `:not(:last-child)` since `.icon` is the `:last-child` or just use `:not(.icon)` there instead.

```css
.navSection {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-table;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #1c948a;
    z-index: 3;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.navMenu .icon{
    display: none;
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navMenu ul li:not(.icon) {display: none;}
  .navMenu ul li.icon {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .navMenu.responsive {position: relative;}
  .navMenu.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navMenu.responsive ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.navSectionWrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.homelink {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navlogo {
    width: 30%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #2C3E50;
    position: absolute;
}

.logoimg {
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
}

.logotext {
    font-weight: 600;
    float: right;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.logotext>span {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #33425B;
}

.navMenu {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navMenu>ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.navMenu>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.navMenu>ul>li>a>span {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px
}

.navMenu>ul>li>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 10px
}

.navMenu>ul>li>a:hover {
    color: snow;
}
```

```html
<div class="navSection">
        <div class="navSectionWrapper">
            <div class="navlogo">
                <a href="#" class="homelink">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" class="logoimg">
                        <h2 class="logotext">Let's<span>Go</span></h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navMenu" id="mynavMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">+<span>Download</span></a></li>
                    <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("mynavMenu");
            if (x.className === "navMenu") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "navMenu";
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You! I got it but I'm a bit unclear about the part "Your HTML uses a.icon but you're targeting in CSS with li.icon." Where is that? And why did you add float: right to .navMenu .icon CSS? Is that necessary?

Comment: @RadVolan you're welcome. `<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>` - the class `.icon` is on the `a` but your css selector is `.navMenu ul li.icon` - so you're trying to apply css to `li.icon` and your html is actually `a.icon` - make sense?

Comment: Yep, so I can make it to work with the icon class in `a` -> `<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>` and use `.navMenu a.icon` ? Right?

Comment: @RadVolan No because you're hiding all of the `li`'s in your responsive media query (`.navMenu ul li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}`), so if you show `a.icon`, it won't show because the parent `li` is hidden.

Comment: Oh I meant with the `:not(.icon)`. But yeah, need to changes some `ul li` to `ul li a` to make it work with the ham menu. But still a bit weird lol (cause im a noob ._.). Anyway, thank you very much @Michael Coker !